# how to determine how many times capacity hits its max capacity

Tags: php, mysql, sql

example
mysql table named "Profile" data as below

```
----------------------
user_id | max_capacity
----------------------
100          3
101          5
103          10
```

another mysql table named "Active" data as below

```
-------------------------
user_id | active_capacity
-------------------------
101          7
103          5
```

please note table "Active" column - `active_capacity` is dynamic its values are changing every second by another script.

I want to determine if my `user_id #101` has hits/over the `active_capacity` of its allowed `max_capacity` which is `5` in "Profile" table. Please note the "Active" table showing that `user_id #101` its `active_capacity` is `7` now.

I would like to to define maximum hit value like `$hit=2` if my `user_id #101` hits/over its `max_capacity` for first time then I want to store its value into another table named "Danger"

storing the `user_id #101` because its active_capacity is 7 now which is over its `max_capacity`

mysql table "Danger" data as below

```
--------------
user_id | hits
--------------
101          1
```

after 5 minute the `user_id #101` its `active_capacity` in mysql table "Active" decrease down to `4`

after another 5 minutes the `user_id #101` its `active_capacity` in mysql table "Active" increase up to `10` so here I want to update the "Danger" table `user_id #101` column `hits` to "2"

please note: i want to update the "danger" table column `hits` value only after the `active_capacity` from "Active table" decrease down and again its `active_capacity` value increase up and hits/over its `max_capacity` value from "Profile" table

this script will work from cron jobs. I need advise, what is most efficient way to achieve the above goal.

Thanks.

Comment: You mention things like "Danger table", "hits column", and time variation, and yet do not describe what these actually look like.

Comment: please see each table example data below of each table named like "mysql table "Danger" data as below"..

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's `on duplicate key update` functionality to do this as one statement. This assumes user_id is a primary key on the Danger table. The SQL also assumes user_id is unique on the other two tables:

```
insert into Danger (
    user_id, hits
) select
    p.user_id, 1
from
    Profile p
        inner join
    Active a
        on a.user_id = p.user_id
where
    a.active_capaciy > p.max_capacity
on duplicate key update set
    hits = hits + 1;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b77f/1)